# FutureBuilder, change AppBar text when future is loaded (with a value of class loaded)

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I have this code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(_model != null
          ? _model!.name // <-- HERE I GET THE ERROR
          : AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loading),
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Home');
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.home,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: RefreshIndicator(
        key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
        onRefresh: _refresh,
        child: FutureBuilder<Model>(
          future: _model,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Model> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return LoadingWidget();
              default:
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                else
                  return _build(snapshot.data!);
            }
          },
        )),
  );
}
```

I need to change AppBar text when Future is loaded (with the property `name` of the `Model` class), but I get this error right now:

> The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Future

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
appBar: AppBar(
      title: FutureBuilder(
        future: _model,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
         return Text(!_model.hasData
           ? _model!.name,
          : AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loading);
        }
      ),
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Home');
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.home,
        ),
      ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I get this error: `The argument type 'FutureBuilder<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'`

Comment: I've made an edit, please checkout.

Answer (score 0):

```
The argument type 'FutureBuilder<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?
```

Flutter appBar is PreferredSizeWidget. for that you occur this error.

> you return Text Widget but it only except PreferredSizeWidget

```
   class MainAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
 const MainAppBar(
  {Key? key,
  this.assetName,
  required this.appBarTitle,
  this.icon,
  this.onEditTrip})
  : super(key: key);

final String? assetName;
final String appBarTitle;
final Widget? icon;
 final Function()? onEditTrip;

@override
 State<MainAppBar> createState() => _MainAppBarState();

@override
Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(58);
}

class _MainAppBarState extends State<MainAppBar> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return AppBar(
  iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: ColorCode.iconColor),
  elevation: 0,
  backgroundColor: ColorCode.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
  title: Text(
    widget.appBarTitle,
    style: CustomTextStyle().title20TextStyle,
  ),
  centerTitle: true,
  actions: [
    if (widget.assetName != null) SvgPicture.asset(widget.assetName!),
    if (widget.icon != null)
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: widget.onEditTrip!,
        child: widget.icon
      ),
    SizedBox(
      width: 5.w,
    )
  ],
  actionsIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: ColorCode.iconColor),
   );
  }
 }
```

> You can create custom app bar for that up this code. and if your future response not return yet you pass empty string.